# Facing issue with Retrofit:2.1.0. It Converts & and = operator to unicode string

Tags: android, retrofit

Actual Request is

> {"feedback":"**android &
>   testing**","form":"Feedback","loginId":"xyz123"}

But **Retrofit** ***converts & operator to unicode***

> {"feedback":"**android \u0026
>   testing**","form":"Feedback","loginId":"xyz123"}

Please help me to solve this issue.

```
public interface APIView {
@POST(URLS.FEED_BACK)
Call<FeedbackResponse> saveFeedback(@Body FeedbackRequest request);
}

public class WebServices {
private static WebServices instance = null;
Gson gson;
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
Retrofit retrofit;
APIView service;

private WebServices() {
    this.gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-     dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();
    this.okHttpClient = new Builder().readTimeout(60,    TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    this.retrofit = new     Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(URLS.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFacto       ry.create(this.gson)).client(this.okHttpClient).build();
   this.service = (APIView) this.retrofit.create(APIView.class);
   }

   public static WebServices getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new WebServices();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public APIView getService() {
    return this.service;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please paste your retrofit interface and any interceptors you have so we can help you.

Comment: hey @iagreen have u seen my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable html escaping in your `gson` instance.

```
this.gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it converting the request to UrlEncoded form, and then reconvert UrlEncoded request to the actual request in a server side:

```
String urlEncoded = "";
    try{
        urlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(yourAwesomeRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        //OMG
    }
```

And on server side, convert urlEncoded to the actual request.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this

```
{"feedback":"android &amp; testing","form":"Feedback","loginId":"xyz123"}
```

Comment: not working with this too.